# How to create "workaround" MAXIFS and MINIFS formulas in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I am using the following formula to calculate the average daily temperature value in column B (see image below) for each day over a 15-year meteorological record (temperature values are in column B and there are multiple per day). Column A contains the date that the record was taken and column D is a list of unique dates to get the average daily temperatures for.

```
=AVERAGEIFS(R2:R47505,J2:J47505,AN2:AN5965)
```

I would like to replicate this formula for the daily maximum and minimum but do not have `MAXIFS` or `MINIFS` formulas in my version of Excel. Is there a workaround to create these formulas?

In the image below, I am trying to calculate the maximum daily temperature in column F; for 01.02.2005, this would be -2.7 for example

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
=MAX( R2:R47505 *( J2:J47505=AN2:AN47505 ) )
```

or :

```
=MAX( IF( J2:J47505=AN2:AN47505, R2:R47505 ) )
```

and :

```
=MIN( IF( J2:J47505=AN2:AN47505, R2:R47505 ) )
```

Using your screenshot to mock up your data, I changed the formulas to:

```
=MAX( IF( $A$2:$A$70 = D2, $B$2:$B$70 ) )
```

and

```
=MIN( IF( $A$2:$A$70 = D2, $B$2:$B$70 ) )
```

here is what I get:

[image]

But are you sure that `=AVERAGEIFS(R2:R47505,J2:J47505,AN2:AN5965)` is giving you what you want?

To get the average for each day, I used:

```
=AVERAGEIFS( $B$2:$B$70, $A$2:$A$70, D2 )
```

I hand checked the values and they are correct.

Comment: Hmm thanks, but still does not work for me

Comment: @Simba06 perhaps post a sample of your data with the desired result

Comment: @Dave Thanks that is a good idea, I have updated the question

Comment: @simba06 Hmm - I see now what the data look like, but I am concerned that your AVERAGEIFS may not be delivering what you want.  I will update and show you - is easier to see with a screenshot.

Comment: I am just realizing that you have an array formula for :  `=AVERAGEIFS(R2:R47505,J2:J47505,AN2:AN5965)`.  I cannot think of a quick way to complete the same with a normal MAX because it will aggregate the results, not iterate them.  Therefore, you would have to copy down the formulas I proposed.

Comment: @markfitzpatrick thanks! I have fixed the averageifs formula. As for the max column, I managed to get the correct result for the first entry but when dragging down the formula I am just getting zeros for subsequent dates :/

Comment: E.g. for F3, I am using =MAX(IF($A$2:$A$50=D3,$B$2:$B$50)) and getting 0, so I am not sure what is going on!

Comment: Maybe as a test, try =MAX(IF($A$2:$A$50=D3,$B$2:$B$50, -1000) ) and see what result you get. Your version of Excel is coercing FALSE as Zero and as your numbers are negatives, the max would effectively taking MAX( -5,-2.7,-8, FALSE, -3...) and converting it to MAX( -5,-2.7,-8, 0, -3...).  If this is the case, I am not sure how to get around it and my version of Excel cannot emulate yours.

Comment: Another thought - is the MIN working?  If so, it would point to the FALSE --> 0 as being the problem.

Comment: @markfitzpatrick I was still having trouble in Excel for some reason. Indeed I was getting false values as you mentioned. In the end I used Google Sheets to calculate the values as it has MAXIFS and MINIFS formulas in-built, then copied back over to Excel. Finally worked! Thank you for your help

Comment: I'm glad you got there in the end, but... what a painful experience!  :-D